# Facebook Page App Supscription

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I am trying to subscribe facebook page to my App. When I am logged into my account and hit the page name to subscribe it get subscribed to the App, but when I switch the account to other Facebook Account , it shows me the FB login page  give me the list of pages on that account and when I hit the page , it says subscribed . But the page is actually not subscribed to the app. Here is the code I have on the subscribe web page.

The app is to connect the page to the FB messenger bot.

```
<script>
                window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                  FB.init({
                    appId      : 'my_app_id',
                    xfbml      : true,
                    version    : 'v2.11'
                  });
                  FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
                };

                (function(d, s, id){
                   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
                   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
              </script>

              <script>

              function subscribeApp(page_id, page_access_token){
              console.log ('Subscribing page!' + page_id);
              FB.api(
              '/' + page_id + '/subscribed_apps', 
              'post',
              {access_token: page_access_token},
              function(response){
              console.log(response);

              });
              }


              function myFacebookLogin() {
                FB.login(function(response){
              console.log('Successfully loggedin', response);
              FB.api('/me/accounts', function(response){
              console.log('Pages retrived' , response);

              var pages = response.data;

              var ul = document.getElementById('list');
              var len = pages.length;
              for( i = 0 ; i<len; i++)
              {
              var page = pages[i];
              var li = document.createElement('li');
              var a = document.createElement('a');
              a.href = "#";
              a.onclick =  subscribeApp.bind(this, page.id, page.access_token);
              a.innerHTML = page.name
              li.appendChild(a);
              ul.appendChild(li);
              }
              });
              }, {scope: 'manage_pages'});
              }
              </script>

            <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="myFacebookLogin()">Get Pages</button>
            <ul id="list">

            </ul>
```

I tried with the page scope as manage_pages, pages_messaging , but it didn't worked

Comment: I checked that I started receiving  the webhook event for the page subscribed. But I can't see that page on my app dashboard under subscribed pages

Comment: Does this other account have a role in the app, too, or is it just a regular user? And if the latter, did you get your app’s use of the permissions approved in review already? Is the page public, or at least visible to your app admin account?